# size difference when converting videio.mp4(small size) to image sequance (far bigger size collectively) using cv2

Tags: python, image, opencv, video-capture

The Problem is that I was trying to extract all frames from a video file and save it in the disk. Everything works fine but when checking the properties of the output directory I came to know that its size is almost 40 times bigger then the its source input file.

When tried to Compress the frame before saving it causes it to loss to much details but in video the frames have quite good details even with so much less size.

The code which I was using is Below.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_path)
if not cap.isOpened():
        cap.open()
while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret and read_counter % step == 0:
            filename = ''
            if len(str(name_counter)) == 1:
                filename = '0000' + str(name_counter) + '.jpeg'
            elif len(str(name_counter))== 2:   
                filename = '000' + str(name_counter) + '.jpeg'
            elif len(str(name_counter)) == 3:
                filename = '00' + str(name_counter) + '.jpeg'
            elif len(str(name_counter)) == 4:
                filename = '0' + str(name_counter) + '.jpeg'
            elif len(str(name_counter)) == 5:
                filename = str(name_counter) + '.jpeg'
            

            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , filename), frame)
        
        else:
            break
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What are `step` and `name_counter` variables? How did you initialize them?

Comment: Yes I did. Name counter is there for sequential naming to save frames and step is number of framers that we want to take into account.
Basically if the video has more then 30 FPS say 60 fos or 90 fps then we just consider every 2nd or 3rd frame accounding to the FPS if video.